# What is the purpose of the capacitor in this circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor, filter, control-system

Is the purpose of the capacitor, C1, to filter out any possible DC component that the input signal has?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You guessed correctly.  This is often called an AC coupling capacitor.  It will remove any DC bias going into the second amplifier.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but is it just to filter DC or can it be used to filter certain frequencies?

Comment: It's also called a "DC blocking capacitor".  It can only filter "certain frequencies" to the extent that the product \$C_1 R_5\$ determines the frequency range where it transitions from blocking to conducting.

Comment: @Pedro It would be helpful if you told us where you got the schematic.

Comment: @DerStrom8 the schematic is from a list of exercises my professor provided